# Артефакты при хранении данных в структуре

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, struct, realm

Есть проблема и не понятно откуда растут ноги. Данных хранятся в БД REALM. 
массив следующим методом:

```
func loadMenu(category: String, completion:@escaping([Recipe]?) -> Swift.Void) {

        var ingredient = [Ingredient]()
        var stage = [CookStage]()
        var photos = [PhotoDish]()
        var recipes = [Recipe]()
        let realm = try! Realm()

        let data = realm.objects(Dish.self).filter("type = '\(category)'")
        for value in data {
            for valIngredient in value.ingredient {
                let ing = ["recipeID": valIngredient.recipeID,
                           "name": valIngredient.name,
                           "count": valIngredient.count,
                           "weight": valIngredient.weight,
                           "photo": valIngredient.photoURL,
                           "image": self.loadImage(url: valIngredient.photoURL, dir: "ingredients") ] as [String: AnyObject]
                let newIngredient = Ingredient(dict: ing as Dictionary<String,AnyObject>)
                ingredient.append(newIngredient)
            }

            for valCook in value.cook {
                let cook = ["stage": valCook.stage,
                            "recipeID": valCook.recipeID,
                            "photoUrl": valCook.photoUrl,
                            "photo": self.loadImage(url: valCook.photoUrl, dir: "stage")] as [String:AnyObject]
                let newStage = CookStage(dict: cook as Dictionary<String, AnyObject>)
                stage.append(newStage)
            }

            for valFoto in value.foto {
                let foto = ["url": valFoto.url,
                            "recipeID": valFoto.recipeID,
                            "image": self.loadImage(url: valFoto.url, dir: "compleate")] as [String:AnyObject]

                let newPhoto = PhotoDish(dict: foto as Dictionary<String, AnyObject>)
                photos.append(newPhoto)
            }

            let newElement = Recipe(name: value.name,
                                    count: value.eat,
                                    complexity: value.complexity,
                                    time: value.time,
                                    category: value.category,
                                    type: value.type,
                                    about: value.about,
                                    ingredient: ingredient,
                                    cook: stage,
                                    photo: photos,
                                    idOwner: value.idOwner,
                                    shared: value.shared,
                                    planing: value.planing,
                                    timestamp: value.timestamp,
                                    recipeID: value.recipeID)
            recipes.append(newElement)
        }
        completion (recipes)
    }
```

самое странное что при заполнении структы появляются непонятные строки значения которые отсутствую в БД.
Данные которые находятся в БД:

```
Results<Dish> <0x7f947a44a6b0> (
    [0] Dish {
        name = Kljhgv;
        eat = ;
        complexity = 3.75;
        time = ;
        category = Завтрак;
        type = salad;
        about = ;
        ingredient = List<Ingredients> <0x604000302370> (

        );
        cook = List<Cook> <0x604000303d50> (

        );
        foto = List<Foto> <0x60400011b5a0> (
            [0] Foto {
                recipeID = IxiH%HQ!OudWYCT0c97C0Qh!sJ6HvhYOqzBHfFiQ6ose3gqY6b4JQgvB2vd6&zKN!qNukQx2zOzE95s87SQccP4lp!NvJ7!9h%ws;
                url = gBJlV28nVwfH61ZSmiYZwRgVcYcL%awahYvPLdh251KOOWu5fK2sFm3gZ%xq6UPforXneq5NBic4U1sKoYaic&LHXFVPXDETRAny;
            }
        );
        idOwner = ;
        shared = 0;
        planing = 0;
        timestamp = 1534430958.59876;
        recipeID = IxiH%HQ!OudWYCT0c97C0Qh!sJ6HvhYOqzBHfFiQ6ose3gqY6b4JQgvB2vd6&zKN!qNukQx2zOzE95s87SQccP4lp!NvJ7!9h%ws;
    },
    [1] Dish {
        name = Lkjh bn;
        eat = ;
        complexity = 3.75;
        time = ;
        category = Завтрак;
        type = salad;
        about = ;
        ingredient = List<Ingredients> <0x604000303450> (

        );
        cook = List<Cook> <0x6040003038d0> (

        );
        foto = List<Foto> <0x60400011fda0> (

        );
        idOwner = ;
        shared = 0;
        planing = 0;
        timestamp = 1534430971.07465;
        recipeID = DbJETiHayOn4LYIVk2oT0Q0$ralCh9!Aux45EB5$SYPSvX@nUmXIAVGvuOzwU69TI6Th0nAx7mV6TzPGDw@8NLsfC8!RIdysBQXB;
    }
)
```

Данные которые попадают в структуру:

```
[CookBook.Recipe(
name: "Kljhgv", 
count: "", 
complexity: "3.75", 
time: "", 
category: "Завтрак", 
type: "salad", 
about: "", 
ingredient: [], 
cook: [], 

photo: [CookBook.PhotoDish(
        recipeID: "IxiH%HQ!OudWYCT0c97C0Qh!sJ6HvhYOqzBHfFiQ6ose3gqY6b4JQgvB2vd6&zKN!qNukQx2zOzE95s87SQccP4lp!NvJ7!9h%ws", 
        url: "gBJlV28nVwfH61ZSmiYZwRgVcYcL%awahYvPLdh251KOOWu5fK2sFm3gZ%xq6UPforXneq5NBic4U1sKoYaic&LHXFVPXDETRAny", 
        image: Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<__ObjC.UIImage>.some(<UIImage: 0x6040000b6740> size {4288, 2848} orientation 0 scale 1.000000))], 

idOwner: "", 
shared: "0", 
planing: "0", 
timestamp: "1534430958.59876", 
recipeID: "IxiH%HQ!OudWYCT0c97C0Qh!sJ6HvhYOqzBHfFiQ6ose3gqY6b4JQgvB2vd6&zKN!qNukQx2zOzE95s87SQccP4lp!NvJ7!9h%ws"), 


CookBook.Recipe(
name: "Lkjh bn", 
count: "", 
complexity: "3.75", 
time: "", 
category: "Завтрак", 
type: "salad", 
about: "", 
ingredient: [], 
cook: [], 

photo: [CookBook.PhotoDish(
        recipeID: "IxiH%HQ!OudWYCT0c97C0Qh!sJ6HvhYOqzBHfFiQ6ose3gqY6b4JQgvB2vd6&zKN!qNukQx2zOzE95s87SQccP4lp!NvJ7!9h%ws", 
        url: "gBJlV28nVwfH61ZSmiYZwRgVcYcL%awahYvPLdh251KOOWu5fK2sFm3gZ%xq6UPforXneq5NBic4U1sKoYaic&LHXFVPXDETRAny", 
        image: Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<__ObjC.UIImage>.some(<UIImage: 0x6040000b6740> size {4288, 2848} orientation 0 scale 1.000000))], 

idOwner: "", 
shared: "0", 
planing: "0", 
timestamp: "1534430971.07465", 
recipeID: "DbJETiHayOn4LYIVk2oT0Q0$ralCh9!Aux45EB5$SYPSvX@nUmXIAVGvuOzwU69TI6Th0nAx7mV6TzPGDw@8NLsfC8!RIdysBQXB")]
```

Откуда появляется непонятная запись о наличии фотографии во втором (если записей больше, то принцип тот же самый). Самое странное, то такая странная ситуация происходит только с этой частью.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена и как оказалась совсем очевидна.

```
var stage = [CookStage]() 
var photos = [PhotoDish]() 
var recipes = [Recipe]()
```

объявлены не в том месте. В итоге они дописывались что влекло за собой накопление данных и некорректное отображение информации.